# Defining a Sample Space S for a Continuous Random Variable

Tags: self-study

I'm trying to define a sample space for a target that a training marksman is shooting at. Namely, it's a circle of radius 1. The marksman is also fairly new, so every point on the target is equally likely to be hit. I'm trying to find a way to define the sample space $S$, but I'm getting a little tripped up on notation. I've got two ways to define it so far:

$$ 1. \, S = \{ (x, y) \in \Re^2 \, : \, x^2 + y^2 \leq 1 \} $$

$$ 2. \, S = \{ (r, \theta) \in \Re^2 \, : \, 0 \leq r \leq 1 \, , \,  0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi \} $$

Do these statements match up with the scenario I'm describing?

Comment: @ kjetil b halvorsen Thank you, I appreciate it. I'm having a bit of an issue with the notation here, but I guess this is also an issue of probabilistic modelling. I mean, if I consider the sample space $S$ to be all the possible outcomes that could happen, I don't see any other possibility...

However, the only experience I have with sample sets is the old "Define the sample space for a die" sorts of questions. I can't find much from my book for questions involving continuous sorts, so I thought this site would be the place to start.

Comment: Both of these look fine to me.  They each capture the unit circle; the first in terms of Cartesian coordinates and the second in terms of [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system).

Comment: @jtobin (1) This is a *disk*, not a circle. (2) For either definition to be correct, it must (in some natural way) correspond one-to-one with the locations on the target. This immediately rules out (2), which contains infinitely many points associated with the target's center.

Comment: @whuber I think I see what you're saying; if I interpret this correctly, I would imagine there might be a point r=0 which acts as the singularity...so, an easy, sorta "hacky" way of fixing this would be to redefine it such that r is strictly greater than 0, and then evaluate the sample space as 0 when r was equal to 0, correct? I'm not even sure how I would go about writing that in decent notation...

Comment: One way would be $$S=\{(r,\theta)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,|\,0 \lt r \le 1, 0 \le \theta\lt 2\pi\} \cup\{(0,0)\}.$$ But perhaps a better way is to avoid mathematical notation altogether so that you can maintain a conceptual separation between the sample space as a set of *possible outcomes* and the other mathematical objects that will be used with it. Thus, you could *define* $S$ to be "the set of all possible locations on the target" and leave it at that. Your formulae (1) and (2) are merely ways of *parameterizing* this set--but they are not the set itself.

Comment: @whuber Whoops - disk is right, sorry.  Point taken on (2), though multiple elements are often ignored when talking about sets.

Comment: @John In this case, though, $(0,0)$ and $(0,\pi)$ (for example) are *distinct* elements of the second version of $S$.  They are not "multiple" in any sense--at least not until you create some mathematical apparatus (such as an equivalence relation) to indicate which elements should be considered "the same."

Comment: @whuber Right you are, cheers.